# Convert SQL views data into csv files using powershell script

Tags: sql, powershell, export-to-csv

I have created a sql view and i need to push the view data into a csv file using powershell script, i have used the below code but the output is not properly formatted, can anyone help me here !!

```
 ##  This is the updated one but even this script exports data in new lines.  

This is the updated one but even this script exports data in new lines.
```

```
    $SQLServer = "Server"  
$SQLDBName = "TestDatabase"  
$SqlQuery = "select * from Successfactors.mimHRQA.Employee;"  
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection  
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True;"  
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand  
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery  
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection  
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter  
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd   
#Creating Dataset  
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet  
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)  
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-csv -Delimiter ";" -Path "C:\Test\exp5.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Output file is as seen below

```
"personIdExternal";"nativePreferredLang";"userName";"CustomString6";"businessUnit";"company";"contract-end-date";"Contract";"firstDateWorked";"UserId";"CostCenter";"lastModifiedOn";"endDate";"createdOn";"firstName";"middleName";"lastName";"formalName";"Gender";"jobTitle";"nationality";"salutation";"createdBy";"phoneNumber";"department";"position";"location";"accountStatus";"managerId";"emailAddress";"customString10";"emplStatus"

"001";"ENG";"Aaron WanBissaka";"Test";"0005";"XUT";"23-09-2020 00:00:00";"Test";"25-11-2019 00:00:00";"xaxdy";"10000928";"23-09-2019 13:31:21";"31-12-9999 00:00:00";"23-09-2019 13:31:21";"Aaron";"A";"Wan-Bissaka";"Aaron WanBissaka";"M";"Analyst";"GBR";"1009";"27002";"+45 11111111";"10000189";"20000391";"DK01";"ACTIVE";"33000068";"VBNCC@test.com";"IN";"55645"
```

[Output.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC3ip.jpg)

---

The current output has values appended in new lines so I am expecting the output to be in a single line ie., each user data in new line with no doublequotes, no header and delimiter to be semicolon.

Comment: The script you've used is not valid. `$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery | Format-Table -AutoSize` makes no sense and will cause dataset filling to fail. Please _edit the question_ and show the exact command. In addition, your data seems to contain newlines, and that's something you need to fix before exporting into a CSV.

Comment: This is the updated one but even this script exports data in new lines.

Comment: Does the raw data contain newlines?

Comment: It is pulling the data from sql views and the values inside views has no new lines.

Comment: According to the screenshot in Notepad, there are newlines. To be sure, use `convert(varbinary, username)` to get a hex dump and see that there aren't cr/lf characters there.